# LM358P not functioning as a non-inverting amplifier

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuits

I am trying to make a simple non inverting amplifier using an [LM358P](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf).

I have run into a problem: the output voltage is 0. I have tried both amplifiers on the chip.

I have listed the pin configuration below:

Pin 8: Positive input of 5.8 V
Pin 4: Negative input of 5.8 V
Pin 3: Positive input of 1.8 V, negative to -ve rail on breadboard.
Pin 2: Resistor 1 to ground
Pin 2: Resistor 2 to pin 1 (output)
Pin 1: Voltage out

The voltage output is 0, measuring from pin 1 to -ve rail.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Circuit Lab]

[image: Bread board]

Comment: Please provide a schematic diagram. You may use the CicuitLab tool on the toolbar of the question editor. Please also post a photo of your breadboard layout

Comment: Resistor 2 to pin 1(Output), not pin 3

Comment: How are the power supplies arranged? Is the measured voltage having a common ground reference with the op-amp supplies?

Comment: Different ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work if supplies have no common ground reference with the voltage you want to measure.

So what you built does not match the schematic that was drawn.